# Can you demonstrate in Python how to post an ad to Facebook's ads API?

Tags: python, facebook

I have found it very challenging to write a Python script to post ads to Facebook in Python. In particular, I want to post ads that show up in mobile news feeds. Can you provide boilerplate code to post one ad, that I can expand on?

My goal is to write a fuller Python script post thousands of ads to Facebook. Most parts of the ads are the same, but they vary base on gender, interest, or device in some specific way.

Comment: Isn't there some example code in the API documentation?

Comment: Python doesn't have first-class support, AFAIK. You need to use a 3rd party wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

This is a year too late, but maybe it'll help someone who comes in through Google or something. :P

Try the Facebook Python Ads API SDK (which wasn't previously available):
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk

There are some examples there on how to bootstrap your session and create objects, but here's a quick snippet:

```
from facebookads.session import FacebookSession
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.objects import AdGroup


my_app_id = '<APP_ID>'
my_app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
my_access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
my_session = FacebookSession(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
my_api = FacebookAdsApi(my_session)
FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(my_api)

new_adgroup = AdGroup(parent_id='act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>')
new_adgroup[AdGroup.Field.name] = 'My Adgroup'
new_adgroup[AdGroup.Field.campaign_id] = <AD_SET_ID>
new_adgroup[AdGroup.Field.creative] = {
    'creative_id': <CREATIVE_ID>
}
new_adgroup.remote_create()
```

Comment: I'm getting error of "Invalid OAuth access token.", with code 190. How I can get access token. can you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You use the example code i wrote with Python. Edit the code for your purpose and with your tokens, ids, etc. I tested and currently using this same script.

[Github link to the script here!](https://github.com/gokhangerdan/publish_facebook_ads/blob/master/script.py)

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.targetingsearch import TargetingSearch
from facebook_business.adobjects.targeting import Targeting
import datetime
from facebook_business.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebook_business.adobjects.adimage import AdImage

access_token = ''
app_secret = ''
app_id = ''
ad_account_id = 'act_'
page_id = ''
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)


params = {
    'name': 'ENTER CAMPAIGN NAME HERE',
    'objective': 'POST_ENGAGEMENT',
    'status': 'ACTIVE',
}

campaign_result = AdAccount(ad_account_id).create_campaign(params=params)
print(campaign_result)

today = datetime.date.today()
start_time = str(today)
end_time = str(today + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1))

adset = AdSet(parent_id=ad_account_id)
adset.update({
    'name': 'ENTER ADSET NAME HERE',
    'campaign_id': campaign_result["id"],
    'daily_budget': 150,
    'billing_event': 'IMPRESSIONS',
    'optimization_goal': 'REACH',
    'bid_amount': 10,
    'targeting': {'geo_locations': {'countries': {'TR'}},
                  'publisher_platforms': 'facebook'},
    'start_time': start_time,
    'end_time': end_time,
})

adset.remote_create(params={'status': 'ACTIVE'})

print(adset)

image = AdImage(parent_id=ad_account_id)
image[AdImage.Field.filename] = 'ENTER AD IMAGE PATH HERE'
image.remote_create()

image_hash = image[AdImage.Field.hash]
print(image)

fields = [
]
params = {
  'name': 'ENTER CREATIVE NAME HERE',
  'object_story_spec': {'page_id':page_id,'link_data':{'image_hash':image_hash,'link':'ENTER FACEBOOK PAGE LINK-PAGE_ID HERE','message':'ENTER AD MESSAGE HERE'}},
}
adcreative = AdAccount(ad_account_id).create_ad_creative(fields=fields, params=params)
print(adcreative)

fields = [
]
params = {
  'name': 'ENTER AD NAME HERE',
  'adset_id': adset['id'],
  'creative': {'creative_id': adcreative['creative_id']},
  'status': 'ACTIVE'
}
print(AdAccount(ad_account_id).create_ad(fields=fields, params=params))
```

Answer (score 0):

This https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole/blob/master/src/fbconsole.py was a great starting point for me when I did what I needed to do with Facebook, although I did not do ads with it.